# Android: startActivity from a receiver also starts the MAIN activity (action.MAIN / category.LAUNCHER)

Tags: android

When i'm using startActivity from a receiver like this:

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(context, NewClass.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);  
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);  
        i.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        context.startActivity(i);
}
```

in some devices (Galaxy S2 android: 4.0.4 for example) - it also starts in the backgrouns the MAIN activity (with action.MAIN and category.LAUNCHER).

--*Edit*--

AndroidManifest :

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:debuggable="true">
    <receiver android:name="com.my.app.MyBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="99999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name="com.my.app.Main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.my.app.NewClass">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEWSCLASS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because in you AndroidManifest.xml the activity has specified two things:

```
              <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
```

Comment: When i open my app i want to use Main.class, but in my Reciver onReceive - i want to start NewClass.class

Comment: I understand that, but android works like this: when you start another activity the activity that was already started goes in background

Comment: You can remove from AndroidManifest.xml the lines that i discribed in my answer.

Comment: But i want to use Main.class as the launcher class

Answer (score 0):

Post your manifest file can help

Remove in the manifest the intent filter for NewClass. 
UPDATE : the intent-filter is not necessary because you make an explicit intent. Intent-filter is usefull for implicit intents.

And try to remove all the flags you set before startActivity. 
UPDATE : Look at intent.setAction